# How to Ignore a few rows with a unique index in a pandas data frame while using groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame `df`:

```
ID  Height
A   168
A   170
A   190
A   159
B   172
B   173
C   185
```

I am trying to eliminate outliers in `df` from each `ID` separately using:

```
outliersfree = df[df.groupby("ID")['Height'].transform(lambda x : x < (x.quantile(0.95) + 5*(x.quantile(0.95) - x.quantile(0.05)))).eq(1)]
```

Here, I want to ignore the rows with a unique index. i.e., all the `ID`s that have only one corresponding entry in them. For instance, in the `df` given, `C` index has only one entry. Hence, I want to ignore `C` while eliminating outliers and present as it is n the new data frame formed `outliersfree`.

I am also interested in knowing how to ignore/skip `ID`s which have two entries (For example, `B` in the `df`).

Comment: You could add an OR in your lambda.  Like this: `df.groupby("ID")['Height'].transform(lambda x : (x.count() == 1) | (x < (x.quantile(0.95) + 5*(x.quantile(0.95) - x.quantile(0.05)))))`

Comment: @ScottBoston ````(x.count() == 1)```` does it tell that there should be at least two rows to involve in the elimination of outliers process?

Comment: Yes.  If there are more than one value, then the first condition is False and the second will go through the evaluation as defined by the second OR condition.

Comment: @ScottBoston It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create an OR condition in your lambda function such that if there is one element in your group, you return True.

```
df.groupby("ID")['Height'].transform(lambda x : (x.count() == 1) | 
                                                (x < (x.quantile(0.95) + 5*
                                                (x.quantile(0.95) - x.quantile(0.05)))))
```

And you can use `(x.count() < 3)` for groups with two or less.